Is it possible to apply trajopt to non-holonomic robots?
I'm trying to generate 3D trajectory or 3D path for the end-effector of the non-holonomic robot (such as mobile manipulator).
Is it possible to apply TrajOpt to these kinds of robots?
I found packages including TrajOpt below.
But I could not understand if it is possible or not.
https://github.com/tesseract-robotics https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/trajopt_planner/trajopt_planner_tutorial.html
If it is possible, could you tell me how to apply? It would also be helpful if you could tell me how to write the constraints of the non-holonomic.
